# Encontrar el menor valor de un articulo en una pagina web (JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

estoy iniciándome en el mundo java mas específicamente en el mundo de pruebas de software con selenium web driver manejando el patrón screenplay, estoy haciendo una automatización de esta pagina Demo --- https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html --- donde es una tienda que presenta al publico unos artículos como maletas y camisas, lo que necesito es encontrar el articulo con el menor valor sin aplicar el filtro de menor valor. les agradezco de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], tu pregunta puede terminar cerrada pues es muy amplia, no demuestra avance o intento de tu parte, dudas claras y código avanzado. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta con lo que has intentado o con el error que te da tu codigo. Hay una manera de hacerlo pero no se como lo estas intentando tu.